# What am I doing wrong with this surface integral?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, vectors, surface-integrals

I'm asked to integrate $\vec{A}=r\cos\theta \ \vec{u_r}+r\sin\theta\ \vec{u_\theta}+r\sin\theta\cos\varphi \ \vec{u_\varphi}$ over a hemisphere of radius $a$.

I take $d\vec{S}=r^2\sin\theta d\theta d\varphi \ \vec{u_r}$, and therefore:

$$\iint_S\vec{A}\ \cdot d\vec{S}=\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}\int_{\varphi=0}^{2\pi}a^3\sin\theta \cos\theta \ d\theta d\varphi=2\pi a^3 \int_0^{2\pi}\sin\theta\cos\theta \ d\theta=\pi a^3\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(2\theta) \ d\theta=\frac{\pi a^3}{2}[-\cos(\pi)+\cos(0)]=\pi a^3$$

However the results state that it should be $5\pi a^3 /3$. So where am I wrong? Or are the results incorrect?

Comment: Please write down the problem in Cartesian coordinates. I suspect that  there is a missing $sin\phi$ in the second term and the field is just $F=xi+yj+zk$

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos It's spherical coordinates, so wouldn't it be $F=zi+yj+xk$? Though there being something wrong with the question is probable.

Comment: I agree but something is not OK! Try to set the problem in Cartesian coordinates!